# React.js 16.8.0 to 18.1.0 Transformation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CubeProvider cubejsApi={cubejsApi}>
      <App />
    </CubeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
```

How to transform this into react 18.1.0. It's written on 16.8.0 now

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
if (!rootElement) throw new Error('Failed to find the root element')
createRoot(rootElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CubeProvider cubejsApi={cubejsApi}>
      <App />
    </CubeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```